# SQL Query to count(x) and group by y

Tags: mysql, sql

This seems to be easy in my head but I can't figure how to write the query:

What I have:

```
user_id  correct_questions
     1                   5
     1                   2
     2                   3
     2                   1
```

What I want to have:

```
user_id  correct_questions(sum)
     1                      7
     2                      4
```

The only thing I get is how often user x has played.

(with `count(correct_questions) GROUP BY user_id`)

Comment: Is it something in the water today?

Comment: Try `sum()` instead of `count()`.

Comment: @Strawberry Don't know, ask  Carrie Underwood!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well only thing you have to do is SUM + group by :

```
select user_id, SUM(correct_questions) as correct_questions 

from yourtable

Group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select sum(correct_questions) from table_name group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `SUM()` function and not `COUNT()` as correctly pointed by "Grodon Linoff"

```
select sum(correct_questions) as correct
from table
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, sum(correct_questions) from tb_name group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

While I wrote this, 10 others wrote the same. Thanks!

---

I just answered my own question within the question.

Of course I have to use sum() instead of count()

```
SELECT *, sum(`correct_answers`) as sum
FROM `user_quiz_rel`
GROUP BY `u_id`
```